# node js mongoose mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using phpstorm, trying to get mongoDB server up and running using nodeJS, i have mongo installed and have created the required folders on the c drive to store database, proceeded by going to command prompt and entering mongod, to get mongo db running....

checked[image] npm ls,mongoose and mongo are listed fine, and are also present in  my package json file.

when i try to run the index file from commmand prompt 'node index.js' i get the following error, see pic for details, i have included, the code used for setting up mongo... i have disable mongoserver from phpstorm repository, and use the one from the mongodb website

"mongodb": "3.0.0-rc0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.0-rc2",

```js
var mongoose =require('mongoose');

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/quaver');

mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
    console.log('connection has been made , and is running')

});

   mongoose.on('error', function(error){
console.log('Connection error',error);
});
```

Comment: The error message is about an erroneous RegExp and send to be independent of Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error sorted by omitting the following lines from the semver.js file, in the node modules folder in the current project

line 203,204

//re[COMPARATORTRIM] = new RegExp(src[COMPARATORTRIM], 'g');
//nodevar comparatorTrimReplace = '$a$2$3';

and line 232

//  re[i] = new RegExp(src[i]);

mongoose now up and running [image]